# How do you return a typed Promise

Tags: typescript, types

Below code works, however it promises to return any thing. How do I change this to promise to return something of a specific type Promise or maybe a union of Promise? buildError returns something also typed as Response.

```
public async getSomething(userId: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => 
    {
        this.axios().get(baseUrl + path, config)
            .then((response: any) => {
                if (response && response.data && response.status === 200) {
                    resolve(response.data);
                } else {
                    reject(this.buildError(response.status || 500, userId));
                }
            })
            .catch((response: any) => {
                logger.error(response);
                const status = response.response ? response.response.status : 500;
                reject(this.buildError(status, userId));
    }
}
```

If I type as Promise, intelliJ complains that Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Response', Property 'foo' is missing in type '{}'. I have tried to type all resolves and rejects as Response. I assume '{}' refers to => {...}, however it is not clear how to type that.

Comment: Using `new Promise` is almost always incorrect. It definitely is in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up doing something like this

```
public async getSomething(userId: string): Promise<Response> {
    return new Promise<Response>((resolve: any, reject: any) => 
    {
        this.axios().get(baseUrl + path, config)
            .then((response: any) => {
                if (response && response.data && response.status === 200) {
                    resolve(response.data);
                } else {
                    reject(this.buildError(response.status || 500, userId));
                }
            })
            .catch((response: any) => {
                logger.error(response);
                const status = response.response ? response.response.status : 500;
                reject(this.buildError(status, userId));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A more correct version of your code:

```
public getSomething(userId: string): Promise<any> {

  return this.axios().get(baseUrl + path, config)
     .then((response: any) => {
        if (response && response.data && response.status === 200) {
           return response.data;
         } else {
           throw response;
         }
      })
      .catch((response: any) => {
         logger.error(response);
         const status = response.response ? response.response.status : 500;
         throw this.buildError(status, userId);
      })
    }
}
```

The strangest thing about this is that you have the same information in both your then and catch clause. This is highly unusual, and I suspect you misunderstood how your 'axois' library works, however.. throwing the 'response' (weird as it is) makes it consistent with your original post.

This sample can be further simplified with async/await. You used the async keyword (incorrectly) in your example, so I assume that you're able to use this:

```
public getSomething(userId: string): Promise<any> {

  try {
    const response = await this.axios().get(baseUrl + path, config);
    if (response && response.data && response.status === 200) {
       return response.data;
    } else {
       throw response;
    }
  } catch (response) {
    logger.error(response);
    const status = response.response ? response.response.status : 500;
    throw this.buildError(status, userId);
  }

}
```

Again we are throwing the response, which is very strange...

Digging a bit into your Axios library, it appears that by default Axios will throw an error with a 'response' property when a HTTP erro occurred. If this is correct, your code sample should actually look like this:

```
public getSomething(userId: string): Promise<any> {

  try {
    const response = await this.axios().get(baseUrl + path, config);
    return response.data;
  } catch (err) {
    logger.error(err);
    const status = err.response ? err.response.status : 500;
    throw this.buildError(status, userId);
  }

}
```